# SQL QUERY TO SSIS COLUMN DERIVED

Tags: sql, ssis

Good afternoon, can someone help me how this sql query developed in SQL SERVER should look like in ssis format in a derived column, please.

I was thinking of a findstring with a substring, but I don't quite understand

```
SELECT  CASE    
        WHEN  RIGHT(SUBSTRING(DE_NOVEDAD,CHARINDEX('/Op. ',DE_NOVEDAD),12),7) like '64%'
        THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT(SUBSTRING(DE_NOVEDAD,CHARINDEX('/Op.',DE_NOVEDAD),12),7),'/',''),'C',''),'.','') 
        ELSE 0
        END 
FROM NAME_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FINDSTRING instead of charindex on ssis.

Use double quotation marks instead of single quotation marks.

Use IIF instead of CASE.

```
FINDSTRING(RIGHT(SUBSTRING([FullTimeString24], FINDSTRING([FullTimeString24] ,"/Op. ",1),12),7) ,"64%" ,1) > 0 ? REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT(SUBSTRING([FullTimeString24],FINDSTRING([FullTimeString24] ,"/Op. " ,1),12),7),"/",""),"C",""),".","") : "0"
```